# What is the lifespan of a static variable in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

#### Background

I have the following two classes `ViewControllerA` and `ViewControllerB`.

```
class ViewControllerA: UIViewController
{
    ...
}
```

For the definition of `ViewControllerB` we also have a static variable.

```
class ViewControllerB: UIViewController
{
    static var hasSeenTheLightOfDay: Bool = false
    ...
    func viewDidLoad()
    {
        ViewControllerB.hasSeenTheLightOfDay = true
    }
}
```

Now lets say my iOS application runs in the following fashion:

```
User Taps App -> UINavigationController -> ViewControllerA -> ViewControllerB ->
                                                                               |
                                                                         User Goes Back
                                                                               |
                                           ViewControllerA <--------------------
```

For the sake of the question, `ViewControllerA` does not hold any references to `ViewControllerB`.

#### Questions

Could someone walk me through the entire lifecycle of the static variable `hasSeenTheLightOfDay`?

1. When does it come into existence?
2. When does it go out of existence?
3. Does it retain the value `true`? or `false`? or does it flip-flop? If `ViewControllerB` is inflated/exited multiple times consecutively from `ViewControllerA`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You asked:

> 1. When does it come into existence?

When you first reference it.

> 2. When does it go out of existence?

It doesn’t.

> 3. Does it retain the value true? or false? or does it flip-flop? If ViewControllerB is inflated/exited multiple times consecutively from ViewControllerA.

It keeps the value you set. It does not flip-flop.

---

[The Swift Programming Language: Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID264) says:

> Stored type properties are lazily initialized on their first access. They’re guaranteed to be initialized only once, even when accessed by multiple threads simultaneously, and they don’t need to be marked with the `lazy` modifier.

Comment: As a follow-up to your third response. Screen orientation changes also have no effect on static variables, correct? The only way to "reset" the value of a static variable is if the user fully closes the app and restarts it again?

Comment: Correct, only reset unless you explicitly set it to a different value or the app is terminated (user force-quits app, user leaves app and the app ends up getting jettisoned due to memory pressure, app crashes, etc.). But merely suspending app and coming back to it will not reset it. And certainly not a screen rotation.

Comment: "When you first reference it" and because you have provided a default value the variable will be referenced during static initialization shortly after the module is loaded.

Comment: @ScottThompson - Statics, like globals, are instantiated lazily, not “shortly after the module is loaded”. As [The Swift Programming Language: Properties](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html#ID264) says: “Stored type properties are lazily initialized on their first access. They’re guaranteed to be initialized only once, even when accessed by multiple threads simultaneously, and they don’t need to be marked with the lazy modifier.”

Comment: Perfect!  I stand corrected.

Comment: "It keeps the value you set. It does not flip-flop" That's not quite true, in the following sense: Given `static var hasSeenTheLightOfDay: Bool = false`, if the very first code reference to `hasSeenTheLightOfDay` sets it to `true`, it is set to `false` and then immediately to `true`. So that's a kind of flip-flop (though, to be sure, not what the OP was asking about). I regard this as a serious flaw in the architecture, because it means that if the initializer is expensive, that expense will be incurred even if it need not be.

Comment: First, this obviously is not the “flip-flop” to which either I or the OP was referring. Second, yeah, that’s weird. But many of us have pet peeves re statics/lazy vars. Top of my list is that `lazy var foo = Foo()` does not provide thread-safe instantiation, whereas `static var foo = Foo()` does. The lack of local static vars within functions (like we had in Objective-C) is a close second.

Comment: Also I want `lazy let`! Just saying. :)

Answer (score 2):

Static properties in Swift are lazy, which means they are initialized when they are accessed for the first time. They never go out of existence, because there's at least one reference to them, the class itself. And the class doesn't get deallocated, it exists during the lifetime of the application.

However, the retain discussion only makes sense for reference types. In your code `hasSeenTheLightOfDay` is a struct, which gets copied every time is assigned to other value, or passed as a function argument.